# Jenkins and OS X Server on the same machine

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, osx-server, xcode-bots

I'm working on a Java App and on an iOs App. I will like to make continuous integration on both projects.

I know that Jenkins can be use for CI on iOs projects, but I have to use OS X Server for the iOs app.

So I would like to know if someone has configured a mac with OS X Server using CI with XCode Bots, and Jenkins on the same mac ?

Is there some constraints to respect configuring OS X Server and Jenkins on the same machine?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just install OSX Server, config XCode CI on it, and check if integration working on my project.

After I install Jenkins, set it up for my other project and it's running pretty good.

I just have to try building the two project at same time, but I don't think that make any problem knowing that Jetkins and XCode bots create new process for each build.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried setting it up on OS X Server but I did it successfully on Mavericks using this guide here:

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-jenkins-automated-build-server-for-ios/

I'd say to just give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: There is also a http://brew.sh for Jenkins and this guide for OS X server http://oemden.com/?p=205 - I have a Jenkins install from brew but only on Mavericks